# Programmatically connect/sync to WMDC via bluetooth with WM6.5 device

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I've been looking around for a way to create this connection automatically and I haven't been able to find anything. I've looked at the 32feet library as well as some others, and while I can use them to "connect" to the device, they don't seem to let me make the WMDC connection.

I'm looking for something to do the equivalent of "Home -> ActiveSync -> Menu -> Connect Via Bluetooth" (it says ActiveSync, but it works fine for WMDC) and then entering the passcode on each machine, but I would like to be able to have as much as possible done at the click of a button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you just need to call repllog.exe with the right arguments:

arguments for replog
none => open default ras connection
/c: provides ConnectioID name
/p: provides Partner name
/d => disconnect
/remote => remote sync
[src: http://microsoft.public.pocketpc.developer.free-usenet.eu/Start-ActiveSync-on-Device_T30140332_S1]

The USB, Serial or BT connection is just a dialup (RAS) connection. Use ConnectionManager to connect to the right Desktop 'Network': [example using CM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98020/Using-the-Connection-Manager) using the Interface name not MapUrl.